Is there any way to change my generic function to get warnings?
Here my generic function defc
    export function defc<T extends Record<string,any> >(f:(a:T)=>void){
      return function(a:T){
        return f(a)
      }
    }


The goal of the function is to mark functions to enforce correct return type.
my problem is that when i use it, i don't get the needed implicitly has an 'any' type
    const foo=defc(function({bar}){//wanted warnings: Binding element 'bar' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
      console.log(bar)
    })

my question is: is there a way to changed defc to get the warning?

You'll never get an "implicit" any warning there because it has a contextual type that is, as far as I can see, unblockable.  Instead you could switch Record<string, any> to object and get a quite similar issue, as shown in this playground link, which gets resolved as soon as you bind the parameter properly like {bar}:{bar: string}. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz yes, extending from object doe solves the problem just fine

bar implicitly has an any type, but that's what you wanted, isn't it? Otherwise you wouldn't have defined defc to expect a T extends Record<string, any>.
With the signature of the inner function you're passing to defc being function({ bar }), TypeScript infers that the type of { bar } extends Record<string, any> and therefore that bar is of type any, and so has no reason to complain about an implicit type.
Even if you changed Record<string, any> to Record<string, number>, TypeScript would infer the type of bar to be number, and wouldn't complain.
Though in this case, it would complain once you try to use the newly instantiated foo with a non-number type parameter:
function defc<T extends Record<string, number>>(f: (a: T) => void) {
    return function(a: T) {
        return f(a)
    }
}

const foo = defc(function({ bar }) { // no issues here, TS can infer that `bar` is `number`
    console.log(bar)
})

foo({ bar: 1 }) // ok!
foo({ bar: "wrong type" }) // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.


P.S. There's a potential bug in your code. I say "potential" because you may or may not have intended the code to behave this way.
Without specifying the parameter type of the inner function (the one you pass to defc), you make it possible to pass whatever arguments one wants to the returned foo function.
function defc<T extends Record<string, any>>(f: (a: T) => void) {
    return function(a: T) {
        return f(a)
    }
}

const foo = defc(function({ bar }) {
    console.log(bar)
})

foo({ bar: 1 }) // this is valid, will print "1"
foo({ notExists: "hm" }) // but this is also valid and will print "undefined"

foo implicitly expects a Record<string, any> and will extract bar from it, but TS won't complain if you don't pass bar inside said Record.
If you know in advance what keys you expect your Record to have, it might be better to define them explicitly.
function defc<T extends Record<string, any>>(f: (a: T) => void) {
    return function(a: T) {
        return f(a)
    }
}

const foo = defc(function <T extends Record<"bar", any>>({ bar }: T) {
    console.log(bar)
})

foo({ bar: 1 }) // prints "1"
foo({ notExists: "hm" }) // invalid, `foo` expects only the `bar` key


yes, that is a good analyses of the code. but is there a way change defc or any other generic way to tell TS: this function is of type that returns a void and can accept an object with multiple paraments, all parameters must explicitly have types". i have many functions like that, each has its own parameters and all must return the same type. I need a concise way to enforce that constraint

Can you give a couple of examples of both input and output you expect for this defc function?

@yigal pinging you in case you missed my last comment.

the defc function is part of js/ts library that I am working on. The goal of the function is to mark functions to designate them as "components". The chief requirement of of component is to return a some specific (and rather elaborate) return value,  here it is just void for brevity.  components also need to accept one argument that encapsulate the parameters. originally i thought that i  need Record<string,any>, but now i see that object would do just fine. and even better because it solves the potential bug that you have mentioned

Your defc function is generic in T, and if the callback you pass in is context sensitive (e.g., you don't annotate its parameter), then generic inference will fail and it will fall back to its constraint.  If the constraint is Record<string, any>, then the type of the callback will fall back to (a: Record<string, any>) => void. At that point, the any inferred for bar is not considered an implicit any, because any is explicitly in the contextual type.  There's no way to selectively block that inference.
I'd say that Record<string, any> isn't really what you're looking for, since it has a string index signature and you're not trying to make that happen. String index signatures allow any property whatsoever to exist, so once the type argument T falls back to such a type, all properties are allowed. Instead, presumably you want T to be constrained to the object type, which can be any non-primitive, but has no known properties:
function defc<T extends object>(f: (a: T) => void) {
    return function (a: T) {
        return f(a)
    }
}

Now if you call defc without annotating { bar }, T will fall back to object, and then ({bar}) => void will be inferred as (a: object) => void, and you'll get an error that the bar property is not expected:
const foo = defc(function ({ bar }) {
    //                       ~~~
    // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{}'.
    console.log(bar)
})

(The error message mentions the empty type {} instead of object, but that's just what happens in the error message, it's constrained to object. You could use {} instead if you want.)  The destructured bar variable is still of type any, but the error message is about the more fundamental problem that bar is completely unexpected.
Playground link to code
